Read/Write to text file, keep special characters but don't change the BOM
It looks like the original file has a BOM but my VBA code breaks it.
The text "ï»¿" or HEX "ef bb bf" is at the start of the file when viewed in Notepad++ with the HEX add-in.
After any attempt to change the file with VBA the BOM is then part of the visible text in Notepad and it stops the original app from being able to read the file.
The original files encoding is UTF-8 with BOM and after any VBA edits it is still UTF-8 with BOM but then you see the BOM in Notepad text.
After VBA the file then starts with the text "ï»¿Ã¯Â»Â¿" and Hex "ef bb bf c3 af c2 bb c2 bf".
Can VBA match the encoding type UTF-8 with BOM? Can this be done in VBA?
So far, I can have special characters like Ω using the stream option but it changes the BOM at the start of the file and causes an error on the app that later reads it or with the first option that changes the characters like Ω to O but doesn't change the BOM and the original app can still read it.
    ' Open the file for writing only if modifications were made
    If fileContent <> modifiedContent Then
        fileNumber = FreeFile
        Open filePath For Output As #fileNumber
        Print #fileNumber, modifiedContent
        Close #fileNumber
        MsgBox "The file has been successfully modified."
    Else
        MsgBox "No modifications were necessary."
    End If

OR
    ' Check if modifications were made
    If fileContent <> modifiedContent Then
        ' Create an instance of ADODB.Stream
        Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        
        ' Specify the stream type (binary) and character set (UTF-8)
        stream.Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        stream.Charset = "utf-8"
        
        ' Open the stream and write the content
        stream.Open
        stream.WriteText modifiedContent
        
        ' Save the content to the file
        stream.SaveToFile filePath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
        
        ' Close the stream
        stream.Close
        
        ' Clean up
        Set stream = Nothing
        
        MsgBox "The file has been successfully modified."
    Else
        MsgBox "No modifications were necessary."
    End If

Not sure if it will fix all my issues but I was not using the ADODB.Stream option in the ingestion side.
So this:
    ' Open the file for reading
    fileNumber = FreeFile
    Open filePath For Input As #fileNumber
    fileContent = Input$(LOF(fileNumber), fileNumber)
    Close #fileNumber

Becomes this:
    ' Open the file using ADODB stream
    With stream
        .charset = "UTF-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile filePath
        fileContent = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With


In order to resolve your issue you need to treat your output as a binary stream. I have modified your original code to achieve this:
    ' Open the file for writing only if modifications were made
'    If fileContent <> modifiedContent Then
'        fileNumber = FreeFile
'        Open filePath For Output As #fileNumber
'        Print #fileNumber, modifiedContent
'        Close #fileNumber
'        MsgBox "The file has been successfully modified."
'    Else
'        MsgBox "No modifications were necessary."
'    End If

    ' Define the output byte array
    Dim outputContent() as Byte

    ' Check if modifications were made
    If fileContent <> modifiedContent Then

        ' Convert the modified text to a byte array
        outputContent = StrConv(modifiedcontent, vbFromUnicode)

        ' Create an instance of ADODB.Stream
        Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        With stream

            ' Specify the stream type (binary) and character set (UTF-8)
            ' stream.Type = 2 ' adTypeText
            ' stream.Charset = "utf-8"          <--- not required
            .Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary

            ' Open the stream and write the content
            .Open
            'stream.WriteText modifiedContent
            .Write outputContent             '<--- output as binary

            ' Save the content to the file
            .SaveToFile filePath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite

            ' Close the stream
            .Close

        End With
        
        ' Clean up
        Set stream = Nothing
        
        MsgBox "The file has been successfully modified."
    Else
        MsgBox "No modifications were necessary."
    End If


Thanks, I'm not sure yet but it looks like the issue was with the creation of the modifiedContent when reading the file in.
Now using CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") and not Open file.

@Tanquen Yes, after Input fileContent is already garbage. VBA does not natively read or write any Unicode.
